# Handling very large numbers in Java and using modulo

Tags: java

I coded this in Python:

```
def su(n,m):
 sum = 0
 for i in range(1,m+1):
      sum+= (-1)**(m-i) * comb(m,i) * (i**n)
 return sum % (10**9 + 7)
```

And I rewrite this in Java:

```
public class third {
    static BigInteger binomial(final long N, final long K) {
        BigInteger ret = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (long k = 0; k < K; k++) {
            ret = ret.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(N-k))
                    .divide(BigInteger.valueOf(k+1));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    static long ontoFunctions(long n, long m){
        long mod = 1000000007;
        long sum = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<=m;i++){
                double a = Math.pow(-1,m-i) % mod;
                double b = binomial(m,i).doubleValue() % mod;
                double c = Math.pow(i,n) % mod;
                sum = (long) (sum % mod + (a * b * c) % mod) % mod;
            }
        return sum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String  lines = br.readLine();

        String[] strs = lines.trim().split("\\s+");
        int input[] = new int[strs.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
            input[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(ontoFunctions(input[0],input[1]));
    }
}
```

The problem is when my input is 100 100 in Python, it would give me 437918130, but in Java it gives me -334729744. but for "5 5", it's ok for both Python and Java.

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing the calculations with `double` values instead of `BigInteger`?

Comment: Integers are 32-bit representations of numbers and have bounds. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1. For arbitrarily large integer values, use `BigInteger` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html instead.